# Creating table using nested data from a web API

Tags: python, sql, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to update a table in my SQL server using the following query but I'm getting an error message. I had originally created the table but had misnamed the columns.

```
cursor = con.cursor()
table_name = 'current_bestsellers'
create_table_query = '''UPDATE current_bestsellers
                                (list_name varchar(250),
                                display_name varchar(250),
                                bestsellers_date varchar(250),
                                published_date varchar(250),
                                rank int,
                                rank_last_week int,
                                weeks_on_list int,
                                isbns varchar(250),
                                title varchar(250),
                                description varchar(250),
                                author varchar(250)
                                price int,
                                age_group varchar(250),
                                publisher varchar(250),
                                PRIMARY KEY(isbns)
                                )'''.format(db=db_name, table=table_name)
cursor.execute(create_table_query)
cursor.close()
```

I'm using the New York Times Best Sellers list Web API to get the data. The schema shown on the sites documentation section is pasted below.

```
{  
   status:"string",
   copyright:"string",
   num_results:integer,
   last_modified:"string",
   results:[  
      {  
         list_name:"string",
         display_name:"string",
         bestsellers_date:"string",
         published_date:"string",
         rank:integer,
         rank_last_week:integer,
         weeks_on_list:integer,
         asterisk:integer,
         dagger:integer,
         amazon_product_url:"string",
         isbns:[  
            {  
               isbn10:"string",
               isbn13:"string"
            }
         ],
         book_details:[  
            {  
               title:"string",
               description:"string",
               contributor:"string",
               author:"string",
               contributor_note:"string",
               price:integer,
               age_group:"string",
               publisher:"string",
               primary_isbn13:"string",
               primary_isbn10:"string",

            }
         ],
         reviews:[  
            {  
               book_review_link:"string",
               first_chapter_link:"string",
               sunday_review_link:"string",
               article_chapter_link:"string"
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

I can't get my code to work once I get to the isbns because the data is nested as well as the data for title, author, etc.

Comment: It's unclear to me what you are asking here - are you trying to determine what your SQL tables should look like to fit the JSON data?